# vertical 3d flip effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create a vertical 3d effect like a ["flipclock"](http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html).

Instead of having a number, I have a picture: the upper half must flip with a 3d transition over the lower half and vice versa.
 The backface contains the half of a new picture, so the result is that when the animation ends I have a whole new image, exactly like the clock which flips from two halves of an image containing the number '3', for example to two halves of an image containing the number '4'.

[image]

I need only one flip, from picture1 to picture 2, not like the clock which goes over and over.
Do you know of any code ready-to-use for this issue? A jquery pluging would be the best for my needs.

I googled a lot but found only horizontal flips with curling effect, like book turning pages, which is not my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved starting from this page:
http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you need: [Apple style counter revisited](http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/)